# XSLT starts with not 'E' or 'Z'

Tags: xslt, xpath, sharepoint

I am very new to XSLT. I am trying to build a custom list view in SharePoint 2010.

Dependant on what the user wishes to see, will depend on what items are returned.
If say they want to see view 1: it will get all ref thats starts with E.
If view 2: all ref start with Z.
If view 3: all ref starts with every other letter.

I have the following code:

```
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="RowLimit" select="30" />
    <xsl:variable name="query_string" select="substring-after($current_url,'sheet=')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="query_sheet" select="substring-before($query_string,'&amp;acYear=')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="query_year" select="substring-after($query_string,'acYear=')"/>
    <!--sheet query assignment-->
    <xsl:variable name="qOptions">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$query_sheet = '2'">E</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$query_sheet = '3'">Z</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>A|B|C|D|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y</xsl:otherwise>                              
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
<!--debugging--->
    <xsl:value-of select="$qOptions"/>
<!-- end of debugging--->
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[starts-with(@Title, $qOptions)]"/>
```

The oitherwise statement currently does not work because i am trying to get multiple conditions into the starts-with statement. I know i am doing this very wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated. If you could try and be a little more hand-holdy with me that would be great cause the syntax of this language really confuses me!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you dealing with single letters, you could define your "otherwise" like this...

```
<xsl:otherwise>ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY</xsl:otherwise>
```

Then your `Rows` variable could be re-written like so

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[contains($qOptions, substring(@Title, 1, 1))]"/>
```

i.e Does the `$qOptions` variable contain the first letter of the `Title` attribute

EDIT: If, you want to match "everything else" rather than "every other letter", then consider re-writing it to this, slightly more long winded way....

```
<xsl:variable name="qOptions">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$query_sheet = '2'">E</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$query_sheet = '3'">Z</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>!EZ</xsl:otherwise>                              
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(not(starts-with($qOptions, '!')) and contains($qOptions, substring(@Title, 1, 1))) or (starts-with($qOptions, '!') and not(contains($qOptions, substring(@Title, 1, 1))))]"/>
```

Comment: The qOptions contains the letter to search for. either E, Z or everything else.

Comment: This works an absolutely treat! never even considered to write it the other way around!